# Given matrix $A$, find the number of solutions of $X^2 = A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Given the matrix:
>
> $$ A = 
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     0 & 0 & 1 \\
>     0 & 1 & 0 \\
>     1 & 0 & 0 \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
>  $$
>
> Find the number of solutions (in $M_3(\mathbb{R})$) of the equation $X^2 = A$.

I tried writing $X$ as:

$$ X = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

And then I multiplied $X$ by itself and created a system with the terms of $X^2 = A$, but $X^2$ is very messy and I got stuck. I couldn't solve this problem. Is there another (and possibly better) approach to this?

Comment: @hardmath Actually both questions specify that the solutions must be in $M_3(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The determinant of $A$ can be seen to be $-1$, so if $X^2=A$, then $\det(X)^2=\det(A)=-1$, which is impossible.